# Issue building Elastic query with or and not contition

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

i am trying to build a query in elastic but it is not working as expected.

Sql query would be

```
select * from xyz 
where  (phone1 = "1234" or phone2 ="1234" or phone3 = "1234")
and status != "Z"
```

I want records which have value of 1234 in phone1 or phone2 or phone3 field and status is not equals to z

I have build below query in elastic but it returns the record even the value of status is equals to z. not sure what i am missing.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "phone1": "1234"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "phone2": "1234"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "phone3": "1234"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "must_not": {
                "term": {
                    "status": "Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could able to figure out the issue, when i query elastic i see data stored as Z for status but in query Z is still returning records, when i compare with small case z, its working as expected. it seems to do with default analyzer